# IF Not taking any decision?

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements, logic

Look at this:

```
foreach(Object Item in comboBox1.Items)
{
    if (Convert.ToString(Item) == Convert.ToString(dsGirasol.Tables["DatosGirasol"].Rows[contador][0]))
    {
        repetido = true;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        repetido = false;
    }
}​
```

Note that both of the possible outputs have a messagebox.  However when I run this, nothing appears at all, and the rest of the code continues to run...

EDIT: Added the surrounding loop!

Comment: Can you provide some additional surrounding code? It seems like that statement could be causing an exception.

Comment: I don't know the larger context in which this code exists, but you're *sure* that there's no exception that's getting silently caught here?  With a silent try/catch around this, you could throw an array index out of bounds exception and continue to run "normally."  Have you tried stepping through the code in the debugger?

Comment: I added the foreach loop.  The item is being compared to an entry in a table (see the comment to the first answer).

Comment: As an aside, perhaps `Convert.ToString` is not the most elegant way to compare items. If you know that they are strings, just use a cast (`(string)item`). If they are not strings but a class of your own, have you considered overriding `Equals()` in your item class and using that?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want the `break` there for? Try this:

```
if (Convert.ToString(Item) == Convert.ToString(dsMaiz.Tables["DatosMaiz"].Rows[contador][0]))
{
    repetido = true;
    MessageBox.Show("Encontre uno igual");
}
else
{
    repetido = false;
    MessageBox.Show("Encontre uno diferente");
}
```

Comment: The break is to break the foreach loop this code is in.  The "item" is an object inside a ComboBox.  This code compares an entry in a table to the entries already in the ComboBox.  If the entry can be already found in the comboBox, then the loop is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Try evaluating the left and right parts of the condition before you evaluate the equality.
I can only imagine that it must be throwing an exception that is silently caught.
This will help you debug the issue.

eg:

```
var left = Convert.ToString(Item);
var right = Convert.ToString(dsMaiz.Tables["DatosMaiz"].Rows[contador][0]);
if (left == right)
{
    ...
}
else
{
  ...
}
```

EDIT:
Now that I see you are using a loop, go back to basics, is the loop even running?
Low tech debugging, check that there are some Items in the combobox and that you are referencing the combo you intended :)

Comment: +1 for debugging procedures and heuristics, someone should really start a page of these!

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is strange, I managed to solve the problem by puting each loop on a separate method, and now it works, thanks for the help anyways!